# How do I limit 'git ls-tree' to certain filetypes?

Tags: git, last-modified, date-modified

I need to generate a list of all the images and css files with the modified dates, from a commit, for example.

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | while read filename; do
  echo "$(git log -1 --format="%ad" -- $filename) $filename"
done
```

How would I modify this to just return jpg, gif, png, and css files?

Comment: In your place I'd man grep, seeking for regexes and multiple patterns.

Comment: I'm trying to build a list of files that I need to purge cache on.  Ideally I'd want to get a list of all files that were modified in a build, but the git ls-tree returns all files in the build.  Since the list from git shows all files, not just those modified, I could settle for limiting to types and then make assumptions based on modified date to current date.

Comment: If you consider my answer relevant to your question you can flag it as accepted. TY

Comment: I don't seem to have the ability to 'accept' it - does that take a certain level of karma?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see @Marco - thanks.  It didn't occur to me I could toss a grep into the mix, for example this slight modification worked well.

```
--name-only HEAD | grep ".css" | while...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a list of all images and css files, ideally, you should pipe your output to something like:

`grep '.gif$\|.jpg$\|.png$\|.css$'`

Of course you could add more relevant extensions your project might contain, such as .bmp, for instance.

If I try `ls |grep -i '.gif$\|.jpg$\|.png$\|.css$'` I get a list of all files in current folder with given extensions.

**Let's take a closer look at this command:**

`$` ensures you won't match any undesired file, such as .css.bak. `$` matches end of line.

`\|` allows you to specify multiple patterns, so you don't need to invoke multiple `git ls-tree` to get the whole list.

Should your repo contain any files with uppercase extensions you might want to add `-i` in order to run grep case insensitively.

Patterns between single `'` ensures dots are interpreted as dots, and not as "any character" as meant in regexes.